# How to stay true to functional style in Scala for expressions

Tags: list, scala, functional-programming, for-loop

I've struggled to find a way to stay true to functional style in for expressions when I need to collect multiple parameters of an object into a List.

As an example, say I have a Notification object, which has both a fromId (the user id the notification is from) and an objectOwnerId (the id of the user who created the original object). These can differ in facebook style notifications ("X also commented on Y's post").

I can collect the userIds with a for expression like so

```
val userIds = for { notification <- notifications } yield notification.fromId
```

however say I want to collect both the fromIds and the objectOwnerIds into a single list, is there any way to do this in a single for expression without the user of vars?

I've done something like this in the past:

```
var ids = List()
for {
    notification <- notifications
    ids = ids ++ List(notification.fromId, notification.objectOwnerId)
}
ids = ids.distinct
```

but it feels like there must be a better way. The use of a var, and the need to call distinct after I complete the collection are both ugly. I could avoid the distinct with some conditionals, but I'm trying to learn the proper functional methods to do things.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I think the real question is, "how to map from [Y(x1, x2), Y(x3, x4)] to [x1,x2,x3,x4]?" which is sometimes called a "flatMap".

Comment: @pst assuming there's no way to get a single list without the use of var, then yes that's the question.

Comment: The `var`/mutation is orthogonal in this case.

Comment: @pst can you clarify what that means? i'm pretty new to scala.

Comment: There is a way to get such a list without such a `var`/mutation. The `flatMap` operation is how to *literally* make the transformation requested. The fundamental question is the same irregardless of the initial assumption (that the operation cannot be performed without `var`/mutations), which is why it (the question) is orthogonal to such assumptions .. although perhaps that is a poor term to use here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For such cases, there is foldLeft:

```
(notifications foldLeft Set.empty[Id]) { (set, notification) =>
  set ++ Seq(notification.fromId, notification.ownerId)
}
```

or in short form:

```
(Set.empty[Id] /: notifications) { (set, notification) =>
  set ++ Seq(notification.fromId, notification.ownerId)
}
```

A set doesn't hold duplicates. After the fold you can convert the set to another collection if you want.

Comment: This looks promising. Excuse my ignorance but what is the /: ?

Comment: That is the short form of foldLeft. I updated my answer to mention this.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your advice. This solution seems to be the most direct way to get a non-paired list of multiple fields from a List of objects.

Answer (score 5):

```
val userIds = for { 
  notification <- notifications 
  id <- List(notification.fromId, notification.objectOwnerId)
} yield id
```

Apply `distinct` afterwards if required. If the id can only be duplicated on a single notification, you can apply `distinct` on the second generator instead.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, instead of just yielding the fromId, yield a tuple

```
val idPairs:List[(String, String)] = for(notification <- notifications) yield(notification.fromId, notification.objectOwnerId)
```

Comment: The thing is, I don't want them paired. I want to use the list of distinct ids to do a db query and create a Map from id to User object. Is there no way to create a List without using a tuple?

Comment: @Kareem You can just call idPairs.unzip() to turn idPairs into two separate lists.

Comment: But then I have to merge them after. Would definitely work, but seems roundabout. Obviously I'm nitpicking but just curious of the best way.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here is my answer to the following:

> How to map from [Y(x1, x2), Y(x3, x4)] to [x1,x2,x3,x4]?

Use `flatMap` (see [Collection.Traversable](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Traversable), but note it's actually first defined higher up).

```
case class Y(a: Int, b: Int)
var in = List(Y(1,2), Y(3,4))
var out = in.flatMap(x => List(x.a, x.b))

> defined class Y
> in: List[Y] = List(Y(1,2), Y(3,4))
> out: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Also, since [`for..yield` is `filter`, `map` and `flatMap` in one](http://www.blumenfeld-maso.com/2010/01/scala-word-of-the-day-for-loops-all-4-kinds/) (but also see ["sugar for flatMap?"](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/10572) that points out that this isn't as efficient as it could be: there is an extra `map`):

```
var out = for { i <- in; x <- Seq(i.a, i.b) } yield x
```

I would likely *pick one of the other answers*, however, as this does not directly address the final problem being solved.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Stream to transform the pairs into a stream of individual items:

```
def toStream(xs: Iterable[Y]): Stream[Int] = {
  xs match {
    case Y(a, b) :: t => a #:: b #:: toStream(t)
    case _ => Stream.empty
  }
}
```

But like pst said, this doesn't solve your final problem of getting the distinct values, but once you have the stream it's trivial:

```
val result = toStream(ys).toList.removeDuplicates
```

Or a slight modification to the earlier suggestions to use flatten - add a function that turns a Y into a List:

```
def yToList(y: Y) = List(y.a, y.b)
```

Then you can do:

```
val ys = List(Y(1, 2), Y(3, 4))
(ys map yToList flatten).removeDuplicates
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Dave's solution but another approach is to fold over the list, producing your map of id to User object as you go. The function to apply In the fold will query the db for both users and add them to the map being accumulated.

Comment: That would also work, but then you have a db query for each distinct user. Seems there's always a trade-off.

By collecting the list I can query the db once and map it:


    val users :Map[Id, User] = User.findAllById(ids).map(u => u.id -> u).toMap[Id, User]

Comment: The fold function can test the map that has been built so far and only get the user from the db if they aren't already in the map.

Comment: Added my comment to quickly. Yes, if you want a single bulk query you need to do as you say.

Answer (score -1):

What about simple `map`? AFAIK `for yield` gets converted to series of `flatMap` and `map` anyway. Your problem could be solved simply as follows:

```
notifications.map(n => (n.fromId, n.objectOwnerId)).distinct
```